# Keep response time on daily basis for .net visual 2013

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, asynchronous, visual-studio-2013

I'd like to keep response time of different services, that i send request to, simply on .txt files daily.

I get responses from different services for web product.

Each service requires different ways of request. For some of them, i use SOAP, for some of them, i use REST or for some other i simply add parameters in url at make post/get request by using `SendAsync` method of `HttpClient`. As i said, these ways are shaped by requirements of the each service.

My custom methods are generally **async**. In that case, how can i obtain response time of each services for each request and record them. The solution may be a way of implement it or a tool that provides what i want.

If there is same question, please do not blame. I've searched and couldn't find. In that case you can simply redirect me.

Thanks in advance.

That's what i've tried for and not seem working.

```
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        results = await Task.Run(() => v_handler.searchProvider(order, CityId, CurrencyId));
        sw.Stop();

        FileManager.GetInstance().WriteResponseTime(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString(), "Search", DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString());
```

Answer (score 4):

Depending how accurate you want to be, at the start and end of each entry Method start and stop a StopWatch and use something like NLog to log the time out asynchronously on a Service level logger.

If you want more accurate than that you could look at hooking into the pipeline and  doing something similar. Just ensure you actual mechanism for logging doesn't add to your response times.

```
private static Logger _log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
public async string DoSomething()
{
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();

    string retVal = await DoSomething();

    sw.Stop();
    log.Info("Took {0}ms", sw.EllapsedMiliseconds);
    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I thought about your first solution, but i think it wouldn't be accurate because of async calls. I couldn't understand your solution for being more accurate. That is the problem, i cannot understand how to implement such thing for the async calls.

Comment: Thank a lot. I'll try to implement and accept if it works.

Comment: @AndrewHarris `async` in the method definition is superfluous if you don't use `await` in this method.

Comment: Absolutely agree @Rabban. It was a dirty simple example of the part being enquired about. Didn't think I had to be explicit about that part. But to keep you happy I will update the example.

Comment: @AndrewHarris i've try the solution. However, it seems not working. For instance when make the call sync i've got much shorter elapsed time, but in this way, other processes interrupts between `sw.Start()` and `sw.Stop()`. That is why i cannot get accurate elapsed time.

Comment: For instance, when i make service call sync i've got 500-600 msec. On the other hand, when i try this solution, i've get deviated results such as 6000, 21000, 14000, (in msec) etc. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you post some code of the async version so I can see what the issue is?